# How to get Private Ips of Azure Vm's

Tags: linux, bash, azure, azure-devops

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the names of the resource groups separated by spaces: "
read -a resource_groups

# Loop through each resource group and retrieve information about its Azure VMs
for resource_group in "${resource_groups[@]}"; do
  echo "Getting information for resource group: $resource_group"
  vm_info=$(az vm list --resource-group $resource_group --query "[].{Name: name, ResourceGroup: resourceGroup, ID: id}" -o table)

  echo "Here is the information about the Azure VMs in resource group '$resource_group':"
  echo "$vm_info"
  echo ""
done
```

I need private ips of azure virtual machines but this bash script not fetching

Comment: Show us what you tired. The query that you have is not looking for the private IP

Comment: i'm trying to get private ips by entering resource groups in my script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
az vm list -d --query "[].{ResourceGroup:resourceGroup, Name:name, PrivateIP:privateIps}" -o table
```

to filter by resource group:

```
az vm list -d --resource-group $resource_group --query "[].{ResourceGroup:resourceGroup, Name:name, PrivateIP:privateIps}" -o table
```